# Generate Json file after order is confirmed

Tags: magento2.3, orders, json

I need to generate a Json file containing information about Order just right after a customer finish his checkout and the order is generated in admin using orderId
This json file will contain data about products shipping methods ... related to this  order.
if you can help

Comment: can you describe it in more details?

Comment: Can you recheck please? ask me if it is not clear for you.

Comment: How customer confirm the order into your system?

Comment: Once A customer did his checkout and the the order is created in admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do following things :

1. create the `events.xml` file on following location.

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
      <event name="sales_order_place_after">
           <observer name="vendor_sales_order_place_after" instance="Vendor\Extensoin\Observer\OrderObserver" />
      </event>
</config>
```

2. Now create `OrderObserver.php` on following location.

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\Observer\OrderObserver.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Observer;
 
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
 
class OrderObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $Orderdata = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

        //Write your logic to create Json file withh the Order information
    }
}
```

Comment: how can I test if it's working please

Comment: Implement the code into extension and check it.

Comment: Yes I created an extension, where can I check if it's working please?

Comment: You can put the log and check that is working or not. and have you read the answer that you need to put the json file logic there into the observer file.

Comment: Do you have just an idea how to get customer data for exple address into json in OrderObserver.php?Thank you

Comment: from the order object you will get all the data. just print the $Orderdata in log so you get idea. If answer help you please accept and upvote, so this will help other in community as well.

Comment: How can I put the generated files in specific path please?

Comment: use file more function to put the file on specific location.

Comment: Sorry I don't get your answer , can you please explain more or give me some tuto?